# wav files playing twice in firefox from ubuntu apache2 servers when using embed tag

Tags: apache, firefox, ubuntu, audio

Issue: Firefox is playing embedded wave files twice (looping it twice) from web page.

At first I thought this may have been an issue with new versions of Firefox, but we have another server which uses embedded sounds and it plays the wav file just once. Delving deeper into this I discovered that this was happening on the two newer servers.

Server info:
Ubuntu OS 12.04.2
Apache/2.2.22

On the servers that have this odd behavior IE handles them as intended (e.g., plays the sound only once), but Firefox loops through the wav files twice. Has anyone else experienced this issue and/or knows of a resolution? The HTML code playing the wav file is:

```
<EMBED src="./Sounds/file.wav" autostart=true loop=false volume=100 hidden=true><NOEMBED>
```

Perhaps this is no longer (or never has been?) the preferred method for playing a sound file? I am open to all suggestions including using alternative coding, but am trying to make this compatible with Firefox, Chrome, IE, and Safari (ordered by preference/priority).

Comment: When using `<embed>`, you are generally relying on browser plugins.  What works for you may not work for someone else.  Specify what it is you're using to play the audio... or better yet, don't use `<embed>` anymore.  Consider using `<audio>` where there is a standard and spec.

Comment: Thank you Brad for the quick reply. Researched the <audio> tag and got things working. Paired each .wav file with an .mp3 and Firefox and IE both seem to be happy now. Thanks again!